# Easiest way to view incoming data (from wireshark) in python

Tags: python, networking, tcp, bots

I have had a personal project (bot) that i would like to get started on. I wish to read via tcp packets from the flash game into python in order to determine what i would like my bot to do next.

With this being said what would be the easiest way to get the data from wireshark into my python compiler. (save it to file asap and read or is there a library that will just read in the current packets). in a perfect world there would be a python lib that would read wireshark while its running.

i need to be able to parse out the name of a event when it happens in game.

I saw scrapy, tcpdump, pcap, pcapy but would like some further input on which might be best suited for me in this situation

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please note, You are supposed to try to solve problem yourself, and if You fail in doing so, then hit over here and ask question about specific problem. If You type `python wireshark` into `google`, You'll get plenty results, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshark being one of them. Do your homework first, than ask.

Comment: dawg i have spent the last 2 days researching... not trying to download any library i don't need was asking for advice or a preference. Who knows maybe my research misled me...